# Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Non-static method Conexion::conectar() cannot be called

Tags: php

Hola estoy tratando de conectarme a la base de datos siguiendo el modelo mvc pero me da el siguiente error, aquí agrego el código del login del controlador del modulo y la conexión, espero que me puedan ayudar y también sirva de ayuda para otras personas que les da el mismo error

> Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Non-static method Conexion::conectar() cannot be called

El login:

```
<form action="inicio" method="post">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="ingUsuario" required>
      
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="ingPassword" required>
      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
     
    <?php

    $login = new ControladorUsarios();
    $login -> ctrIngresoUsuario();

    ?>
</form>
```

Aquí agrego el controlador para que me ayuden a detectar el error.

```
// Ingreso de usuario//

class ControladorUsarios{

    public function ctrIngresoUsuario()
    {

        if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"]))
        {
    
            if (preg_match('/^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) && preg_match('/^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])) {
                
                $tabla = "usuarios";
                $item = "usuario";
                $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];

                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlmostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);
                var_dump($respuesta);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí agrego el EL MODELO:

```
<?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios{
    public static function MdlmostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();
    }
}
```

Agrego la conexión:

```
class Conexion{
    public function conectar(){
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=posmax","root","");
        $link->exec("set names utf8");
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: No se ve dónde usas el método `conectar()`, pero si lo llamas como `::conectar();` debería ser `->conectar();`. Aunque sería mas apropiado que extendieras la clase PDO.

Comment: O defines el método como estático o lo invocas como metodo no estatico. al usar ´::´ haces referencia a que estás llamando a un método estatico cuando no lo es, lo correcto sería en dicho caso llamarlo con ´->´

Answer (score 0):

modifica la declaracion de la clase `ModelosUsuarios` por

```
class ModeloUsuarios extends Conexion {
```

Ahora puedes llamar al metodo `conectar` de la clase `conexion`

```
$stmt = parent::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
```

Comment: Si tiene otros modelos tendría una conexión por cada modelo; un consumo innecesario de recursos.